# Best way to concatenate plain text files?

Tags: .net, windows, command-line, windows-console

I have a whole bunch of plain text files named as follows: file1.txt, file2.txt, ..., file14.txt, ...
I want to concatenate all of them IN PROPER ORDER to one .txt file.
How should I do this programmatically?
Batch file running in a command window?
Or write a Windows console app?

Either way, could I have the code? Thanks.

More info:

- large number of files. A hundred or more each time I do this report.
- dir won't give the files in proper sequence: file10.txt appears before file2.txt for example, that's why my emphasis. It seems a for i from 1 to n concatenated to the file name prefix is the best. But I don't know how to do this either in batch mode or to execute command from Windows program.

I am leaning towards doing a Windows console app. Will something like this work?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strCmdLine;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
        process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();


        Int16 n = Convert.ToInt16(args[1]);
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            strCmdLine = "/C copy more work here " + args[0] + i.ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
            process1.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a large number of small files?  A small number of large files?  A little of both?

Comment: -1 for 'could i have the code?'

Comment: Is this a one time thing?  If so, just `copy file1.txt+file2.txt+file3.txt+and.so.on.txt destination.txt`

Comment: There seems to be a hidden challenge in here: if the files are named as he says, then getting them in proper order would require either ordering them manually (as @Michael Burr suggests) or `StrCmpLogicalW` (which is how explorer sorts), as the command prompt won't sort the numbers properly if the number <10 don't have zero padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work well if you're willing to invest a minimum of time. For a compeltely automated process you would need to figure out the number of files (which isn't too hard, bu I omitted from here). But for just 20 reports this should probably do fine.

Furthermore, the process in the batch file isn't optimal. In fact, it's horrible. I think it's *O*( *n* !). It's probably much better to use the version below the batch file.

As a batch file:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1"=="" goto begin
echo Usage: %~n1 ^<N^>
echo where ^<N^> is the highest number that occurs in the file name.
goto :eof

:begin
set N=%~1
rem create empty file
copy nul temp.txt
rem just loop from 1 to N
for /l %%x in (1,1,%N%) do call :concat %%x
rename temp.txt result.txt
goto :eof

:concat
  copy temp.txt+file%1.txt temp2.txt
  move /y temp2.txt temp.txt
goto :eof
```

Untested, but it's pretty straightforward, so I doubt there's too many bugs in it.

Alternatively, I just thought that the following would work even easier (on the command line):

```
(for /l %x in (1,1,N) do type file%x.txt) > result.txt
```

Just replace `N` with the highest suffix you have.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient code, but you should be able to get the idea:

```
        Dim files As String()
    Dim tempFile As String
    Dim orderedFiles As New Dictionary(Of Int32, String)
    Dim fileNumber As Int32
    Dim filePos As Int32
    Dim dotTxtPos As Int32
    Dim fileData As String
    Const CONST_DEST_FILE As String = "c:\tempfiles\destination.txt"

    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\tempfiles", "file*.txt")

    For Each tempFile In files
        If tempFile.ToLower.Contains("\file") = False Or tempFile.ToLower.Contains(".txt") = False Then
            Continue For
        End If

        filePos = tempFile.ToLower.IndexOf("\file") + 5
        dotTxtPos = tempFile.ToLower.IndexOf(".txt", filePos)
        If Int32.TryParse(tempFile.ToLower.Substring(filePos, dotTxtPos - filePos), fileNumber) = True Then
            orderedFiles.Add(fileNumber, tempFile)
        End If
    Next

    If System.IO.File.Exists(CONST_DEST_FILE) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(CONST_DEST_FILE)
    End If

    fileNumber = 0
    Do While orderedFiles.Count > 0
        fileNumber += 1
        If orderedFiles.ContainsKey(fileNumber) = True Then
            tempFile = orderedFiles(fileNumber)
            fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(tempFile)
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(CONST_DEST_FILE, fileData)
            orderedFiles.Remove(fileNumber)
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: How many files are you talking here?  Let me know and I'll write some code that handles it.

Comment: More than a hundred files each time I do a report. And I need to do about 20 reports like this.

Comment: Joey, it works just fine using the same file as input and output, but may have weird results if that file is not first in the list of files copied.

Comment: @Robert: that's an awful lot of code considering it can be done in three lines...

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows, install cygwin so you can have a bash shell, then:

for i in {1..N} ; do cat ${1}.txt >> all.txt ; done

Where N is the number of files you have,  The files will all be concatenated in all.txt

Comment: dang- typo!  the 1 inside ${1}.txt should be an "i" --> ${i}.txt

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of possibilities. If you do a `dir` at the command line, and they show up in the order you want them, things are pretty easy -- you can do something like:

```
copy file*.txt destination.txt
```

That will have a couple minor side-effects -- it'll stop reading any given file at the first `control-Z` it encounters, and it'll append a `control-Z` to the end of the file. If you don't want those to happen, you can add a `/b`:

```
copy /b file*.txt destination.txt
```

If the "directory" order isn't the order you want, then you can do something like:

```
for %c in (a.txt b.txt c.txt) copy destination.txt+%c
```

where `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt` (etc.) are the files you want copied, listed in the order you want them copied (and, obviously enough, `destination.txt` is the name you want to give to the result where you've put them all together. Alternatively, you can list them all in one command line like `copy a.txt+b.txt+c.txt destination.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the following Windows PowerShell one liner (spread over four lines here for readability):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | 
    Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } | 
    gc | 
    sc result.txt
```

`Get-ChildItem` retrieves the file names, but they will be in the wrong order (sorted ASCIIbetically rather than alphabetically).

The `Sort-Object` cmdlet is used to sort the file names as you specified, by padding out the numbers in the file name before comparing the names.

`gc` is an alias for `Get-Content`, which reads the contents of all the input files.

`sc` is an alias for `Set-Content`, which writes the result to the specified file.

---

Here is an alternate approach using C#, in case you can't/won't use PowerShell:

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string s1, string s2);

    static void Main()
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Path\To\Files", "*.txt");
        Array.Sort(files, StrCmpLogicalW);
        File.WriteAllLines("result.txt", files.SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file)));
    }
}
```

This uses the `StrCmpLogicalW` function to get the file names in the right order (that function is actually what Windows Explorer uses to sort file names).

Comment: @Joey: if the file name has only one number, and all file names are otherwise the same, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt, you can execute,
`type *.txt > destination.txt`

> Note: This also concatenates text files under sub-directories

Answer (score -1):

i remember of a single very useful program: split & concat. for mac os x... don't know if had another os versions... does the work! http://loekjehe.home.xs4all.nl/Split&Concat/

Comment: No, this is OS X only -- no Windows version.